# Vendor who sells Zip+4 from Semaphore corporation

Tags: zip4

I need a vendor who sells zip4 CD from Semaphore corporation. I would like to input the address data and zip and then mapped/output that correct address and Zip+4.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a good reason you don't just buy them from [Semaphore](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/home/contact.html) directly?

- [How to order ZP4](http://www.semaphorecorp.com/cgi/order.html)

Comment: Looks like they require a US mailing address.  Do you live in the States Chitrarekha?

Comment: Yes, Chicago Illinois